# Eclipse User Interface glitch

Tags: eclipse

So I wanted to start learning Eclipse but ran into a strange error. I have tried re-installing Eclipse multiple times and changing the theme but to no avail. The UI ends up always looking like this:

[image]

EDIT: I figured out a solution. Instead of deleting the eclipse exe on my computer and downloading a new one, I searched for files and programs on my computer with the keyword "eclipse" and literally deleted them all (except for files noted "important system files"). After deleting 1,500 files, I redownloaded the latest version and have no problems....yet

Comment: What are your computer specs?  Which version of Eclipse did you download and install?

Comment: Windows 8 64 bit and I downloaded the Eclipse Standard 4.3.2 for Windows 64bit

Comment: That's not your entire specs.  What's your CPU and RAM?  Your GPU (graphics card)?

Comment: My bad! it is an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz. The RAM 4.00GB (3.89 usable). The GPU is a Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000